# Disable property change detection in migration EF Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-7.0

I am using code-generated Ids for my entities. Also I use EF Core to seed some master data in database and every time I add new migration EF detects changes for those ids (as they basically new) and adds update script to change them in DB.
I have smth like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
            .HasData(new User( { Id = NewId.NextSequentualGuid() } ))
```

What I would want is to have some extension that will ignore change detection

```
modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
            .HasData(new User( { Id = NewId.NextSequentualGuid() } ))
            .IgnoreChangeDetectionFor(u => u.Id)
```

Using .NET6 + EF Core 7.0.5

Is it possible? And if not - what would be the best workaround?

Thanks!

Comment: The Change Detection can be turned off at the `DbContext` level by the `dbContext.ChangeTracker.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;` or you can use the `.AsNoTracking()` for the fetching the records through the DbContext.

Comment: @SathishGuruV I want to disable change tracking only for Id property and only for seeded master data inserted into db during migration

Answer (score 1):

You wrote a configuration for the `User` entity that every time you add a new migration, it create a new `NewId.NextSequentualGuid()` and new migration is created for the new ids. you can use a hard code `Id` for user to prevent creating new migration
(it's not a good idea for `Id`).

According to [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/intro?view=aspnetcore-3.1#initialize-db-with-test-data) better way is use this to using seed data.

```
public static void Initialize(this IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    using (var scope = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IServiceScopeFactory>().CreateScope())
    {
        var dbContext = scope.ServiceProvider.GetServices<YourDbContext>();

        if(!dbContext.Users.Any())
        {
            dbContext.Users.Add(new User({Id = NewId.NextSequentualGuid()});
            dbContext.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
app.Initialize();// in program file
```